# I managed to get stuck with my Nexus 4 Ubuntu Phone, I can't reflash it back to the original ubuntu phone image?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-touch, phone

I'm researching development on this phone and downloaded a number of packages using apt-get. It ran out of space and stopped. I can't do an apt-get purge because there is no space left ...

I tried using adb to push the image again but it's been stuck for hours without progress. I'm thinking the lack of space has something to do with it.

Is there a way to flash it using the SD card or some other mechanism that isn't dependend on storage space available on the phone?

Otherwise the phone works phone, it's not bricked.

Thank you, Caesar.

This is what I get during flashing using adb:

```
$ ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --wipe
2015/08/10 09:19:13 Expecting the device to expose an adb interface...
2015/08/10 09:19:13 Device is |mako|
2015/08/10 09:19:14 Flashing version 22 from ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device mako
2015/08/10 09:19:21 Start pushing /home/hduser/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu/mako/version-22.tar.xz to device
2015/08/10 09:19:22 Start pushing /home/hduser/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/custom-8ae81b5d8eaf3f6fc66b4646d4187ff9303353abc62953326bde48e601bc8641.tar.xz to device
2015/08/10 09:19:22 Start pushing /home/hduser/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-62e6cb43ab375213838c613fa66c73224920700ff1b2887b617a0c2b53ce00f2.tar.xz to device
2015/08/10 09:19:22 Start pushing /home/hduser/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-9757249d38ed16e6f64001d84cbb99e95289955deef433d9f00c0b3bc1f0ab51.tar.xz to device
2015/08/10 09:19:22 Done pushing /home/hduser/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu/mako/version-22.tar.xz to device
2015/08/10 09:19:22 Start pushing /home/hduser/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2015/08/10 09:19:22 Start pushing /home/hduser/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2015/08/10 09:19:22 Done pushing /home/hduser/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2015/08/10 09:19:22 Done pushing /home/hduser/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2015/08/10 09:20:08 error pushing:
```

[...........]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a link which helped me flash Android back to the phone. I can then flash it back to a fresh Ubuntu Phone image.

Here's the link: [[GUIDE] Nexus 4 - Factory Image Restore](http://forums.androidcentral.com/nexus-4-rooting-roms-hacks/223923-guide-nexus-4-factory-image-restore.html)

Comment: I think if you reinstall Ubuntu touch from bootloader, It's not required to flash android back.

Answer (score 1):

When I break Ubuntu touch on Nexus 4 and it can't reboot anymore, I use :

```
ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap
```

When phone is in bootloader (volume down + power button) following this guide : [Install ubuntu touch](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/). You lose data (so backup needed before)

Otherwise when the phone boot normally and for some others problems, I use the same command without the --bootstrap option and the phone on in developer mode (following the same guide)

You can for example use (or without the --revision option and maybe a different channel) :

```
ubuntu-device-flash --revision=[specific image revision number] touch --channel=rc-proposed
```

When you use this, you don't loose data and I think it could solve apt-get issues (for example if you have installed somes packages with apt, it will remove them)

Maybe using this command you will get the same "pushing error" (already happened to me), then you should try several times and maybe use an other cable or usb port (don't really know why this error is happening). For exemple, sometime I've tried it like 10 or 15 time.

If you still have "pushing error" anyway, you could try to flash from bootloader (loose every data and apps, like the --wipe option you used I think)

Hope this could help,